# You are not authorized to access SendGrid, please contact Support

Tags: heroku, sendgrid

I'm having trouble configuring the SendGrid add-on for Heroku.

Yesterday, I got the SendGrid addon for a heroku app. In heroku, I clicked on the SendGrid add-on link. This brought be to SendGrid. There, SendGrid sent an authentication email to the default that Heroku gave me (appXXXXXXXXX@heroku.com). I didn't do anything else, I just closed the page.

Today, I logged into Heroku again and clicked on the SendGrid add-on link. A new tab opened and I got a 403. After seeing [this](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/heroku-credentials/) SendGrid page, I decided to log in to SendGrid manually with credentials from the Heroku config variables. The username was appXXXXXXXXX@heroku.com, same as above. This gave me the error

> "You are not authorized to access SendGrid, please contact Support."

I am currently waiting to hear back from their support team, but thought that asking SO might be quicker. Does anyone know what I did wrong and how to gain access to the SendGrid config?

EDIT:
There are some SendGrid tickets about this, but there is no explanation or resolution: [#806](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/issues/806), [#874](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python/issues/874)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it centers on customer service of a commercial product. Please see [Why Can't I Ask Customer Service Related Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions) for more information.

Answer (score 16):

A few days later, they sent me this email:

> Hi Joshua,
>
> We'd like to know a little more about the email you'll be sending through SendGrid. Please elaborate on the following:
>
> 1. The nature of your business, the services you provide, and your potential customer base
> 2. Your sending frequency and volume
> 3. How you collect your recipient addresses (link to opt in page, or sign up process)
> 4. How you will allow your recipients to opt out of your emails (whether you plan to use SendGrid's one-click unsubscribe feature, or if you have your own method)
> 5. The types of messages you will be sending (transactional or marketing)
>
> Please reply at your earliest convenience in order to continue the activation process. Thanks for your cooperation!
>
> Best,
>
> Justin

After responding to their questions, they discontinued my account. I had thought that they just want to know that I was a human and not a bot, but it turns out they were looking for something else. Be careful when responding to this email!

To answer my question: I did nothing wrong before receiving the email. After receiving the email, make sure that you tell them that you aren't spamming people with email and you only send people emails when they explicitly ask for them. The quickest way to get access would be to check your email consistently.

Comment: Exactly the same

Answer (score 2):

This most likely needs to be resolved by Sendgrid support. They may have suspended your account as your account might have just hit one of their automatic triggers for whatever reason. Their security/compliance team should be able to sort you out.

Comment: how can I actually contact their support without being able to login? Since on every route I found so far to create an support request I was created with a "please login to send the request" kinda message. o.O

Comment: Yes, Exactly - how can you contact customer support if you can't even login! I have been pretty frustrated with this too.

Comment: Apparently this is still a thing, just happened to me on a brand new account. I just want an SMTP provider for my personal website... guess I'm going elsewhere.

Comment: This is the worst experience I ever had while signing up on a website. When I login, it tells to go to support page to resolve errors, when I go to contact their support, it tells me to login before contacting and I can't login because my error is not solved. What?

Comment: Honestly the worst experience I've had signing up for a service. It said my account was not authorized. I've emailed their support with no response for 2 days now and I've dmed their twitter support who were no help at all (they just told me to email the support email). Guess I gotta look for another service, sucks..

Comment: Still an issue as of 2023

Comment: You should be able to raise the issue without login in at https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us under "Trouble Logging In?"